# How to use the USB/HID port with objective-c under a Mac environment

Tags: objective-c, c, usb, osx-snow-leopard, hid

I try to implement an application in snow Leopard, Reading Data from USB/HID device.In  my application  i  tried following steps:

1. IOHIDManagerCreate()
2. CreateDeviceMatchingDictionary()
3. IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching()
4. IOHIDManagerOpen()
5. IOHIDManagerCopyDevices()
6. Create a Reference for device(IOHIDDeviceRef)
7. Based On the  IOHIDDeviceRef i Fetch device details such as(Device ProductIDKey, Device VendorIDKey,Device ProductKey,Device Serial NumberKey,Device VersionNumberKey ect.)
8. IOHIDDeviceOpen(),ie :Using IOHIDDeviceRef i opened Device;
9. IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements(); Ie Copy Matching Elements from the Device;
10. Create a Reference element(ie IOHIDElementRef);
11. Using IOHIDElementRef i retrieved Device Usage,Device Cocookie,Device UsagePage etc.
    Up to this My application working Fine.

**My doubts are**

1. How can read data From Endpoint 1, My device is special purpose device having only one End point(Interrupt no synchronization data  end point)?
2. Is their any Pipe associated with end point 1(HID Device)?;
3. Is their any ReadPipe and WritePipe functions in  HIDManager Based Application?
4. Is it possible to retrieve data from USB/HID using IOHIDDeviceSetReoprtWithCallback()?

Every thing Did based on this Link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW7 ...

Thank you so much for your help ..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use HID functions with non-HID device.
HID is Human Interface Device. Any HID device must conform "Device Class Definition for HID".

I suspect, your device does not conforms this specification.

So you should use other OS interface to work with your device. I suggest to use [libusb](http://libusb.org/). This is cross-platform library for working with USB devices on low level. It will allow you to read/write your endpoint directly.